# pdfView react native ios cant zoom

Tags: react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-ios, pdfview

In react native,installed **react-native-pdf** and **react-native-fetch-blob**.The PDF can view.The problem is while **zooming (double tap or pinch)**, the **iOS** screen move to left top corner part and showing the empty space,android zoom working fine.Please assist me on this.Thanks